# Missing Tensorboard Node Memory Information

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gpu, tensorboard

I am trying to get information on how much memory my graph will require and so I'm trying to examine byte information of different graph components in tensorboard using the [`tf.RunMetadata`](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz) train option. The training part of my code looks like this:

```
sess=tf.Session
...

for itr in xrange(MAX_STEPS):
    train_images, train_annotations = train_dataset_reader.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    feed_dict = {x: train_images, y: train_annotations}
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

    #Tensorboard summary tester
    if itr % 1000 == 0:
        s = sess.run(merged_summary, feed_dict=feed_dict,options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

        writer.add_summary(s, itr)
        writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'sted%d' % itr)
```

However I still don't see any memory statistics on my tensorboard graph. The output looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem just before. The memory information is only shown with a specific "Session runs". So your problem is that there is no Session runs.

[image: Session runs image]

In my case, run again after removing the previous logdata, it was solved.